# Meaning of assignment in a Flow condition $$[TR:EU]

Tags: visual-workflow

Can anyone please advise on the meaning of the following assignment in a Flow condition?

[image]

The concern is about the term: $$[TR:EU].

For the condition to work the Account has to contain $$[TR:EU]. Does that mean the Account should contain both substrings 'TR' and 'EU' or only one of them?

1. SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%$$[TR:EU]%' does not return any data in the org
2. SOQL documentation does not state anything about such filtering

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm

3. There are no labels in the org with such naming

Comment: On the face of it this looks like nonsense. However, perhaps there is more context available from other elements in the flow?

Answer (score 0):

The name would need to contain the entire string "$$[TR:EU]". It looks like a Regex but it is not an expression.

Comment: It doesn't look like a regex expression because 1. $ is the end of input match character so this being at the start would be nonsense. 2. Having two unconditional/contextless end of input matches would never work.